# How to copy command output in ansi-term mode?

Tags: eshell, ansi-term

In `ansi-term` mode, is there a way to copy the command output? This is quite easy in `eshell`, but sometimes eshell behavors not exactly the same with `bash`. For example:

1. eshell doesn't know how to auto-complete `sudo apt-...` command.
2. eshell requires to input password each time I run a sudo command.

So I have to use `ansi-term` from time to time.

Comment: If your only problems are those two listed above you can also use `shell` instead of `eshell`.  I only use `ansi-term` when I run ncurses applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-c C-j` to activate term-line-mode, then, the terminal buffer act more like a normal text-buffer. Switch back to character mode with `C-c C-k`.

You may be intersted by this function that will help you toggle, between the two modes:

```
(require 'term)

(defun jnm/term-toggle-mode ()
  "Toggles term between line mode and char mode"
  (interactive)
  (if (term-in-line-mode)
      (term-char-mode)
    (term-line-mode)))

(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'jnm/term-toggle-mode)
(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'jnm/term-toggle-mode)

(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'jnm/term-toggle-mode)
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'jnm/term-toggle-mode)
```

Courtesy of [Joel's Journal](https://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/switching-between-term-mode-and-line-mode-in-emacs-term/)

Comment: Wow, `C-c C-k` and `C-c C-k` solved my problem well. The function mean no matter in what mode, just use `C-c C-j` toggle the two mode. (and `C-c C-k` works the same way), right? But the default Emacs `C-c C-k` always go back to term-mode is more straight forward.

Comment: @Nick I don't really understand your point :\

Comment: My apologize. I made a typo in the previous comment. I mean since `C-c C-j` and `C-c C-k` toggle the two mode well, why Joel write a function to map them in both mode? Does he want to toggle no matter whether `C-c C-j` or `C-c C-k` are pressed?

Comment: @Nick, yes, that is exactly what he wants, toggle whatever the command used, probably because it may be hard to remember what command to use. It is just a suggestion, you're not obliged to use this.

Comment: I see. Thank you for you answer and explanation. Really helpful!